# Bind a form field in Play 2.0 with a constant value?

Tags: forms, scala, binding, playframework-2.0

I have a scala form with several fields.The fields in the form map to the member variables of a Java class. I want to bind one of the fields(say userId) with a value (I dont want the user to enter values for this field. Instead i want to pass this as a parameter to the scala template). However, i was unable to manually bind a form field. Any help is highly appreciated.

See the sample below for easier understanding :

```
`@(itemForm: Form[Item], user: User)
 @import helper._
 @main("Item list") {
 @if(user != null) {
    @form(routes.Application.newItem()) {
    @itemForm("userId") = @user.id /**I want to bind the userId form field */
        @inputText(itemForm("title")) 
        @inputText(itemForm("description"))
        @inputText(itemForm("price"))
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
}
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it would be better to pass it as action's argument (remember to modify routes declaration)

```
@form(routes.Application.newItem(user.id)){
   ....
```

you can also just use common html

```
<input type="hidden" name="userId" value="@user.id" />
```

**edit:**

Validation in action.Note: it doesn't make sense to display errors on the page next to hidden field, so you do not need placeholders for error messages. It's up to you to pass VALID value into the hidden field. Displaying validation errors to user who can not change the value of hidden field is bad conception.

```
public static Result newItem(){
    Form<ItemModel> itemForm = form(ItemModel.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (itemForm.hasErrors(){
        return badRequest(newItemView.render(itemForm));
    }    
    itemForm.get().save();
    return ok("Your new item is saved...");
}
```

Comment: I want to bind user.id to a form field so that all validations and contraints would be taken care.

Comment: You can validate it anyway as validation is performed after data send to newItem() action...

Comment: BTW, if (as I assume) your user id is always ID of the logged user, you do not need to pass it via form at all, you can just retrive it directly in newItem() action - it's better and safer solution.